# Fairly basic query (maybe needs subquery and or outer join)?

Tags: sql, vbscript

I am not sure why my brain can't process this right now but it seems like this would be an easy query to write.

I have 2 tables:

```
- Orders
(pk)orderID
customername
orderDate
```

```
- OrderDetails
(pk)detailsID
orderID
productName
```

So when a new order is placed, one row gets added to Orders with customer info and in the orderDetails table a row gets added for each product ordered.

So picture these 2 layouts:

```
ORDERS
orderID     customerName    orderDate
1           John Smith       2/21/2020
2           Bill Adams       2/21/2020
3           Susan Conrad     2/21/2020
4           Amy Fetcher      2/21/2020
```

```
ORDERDETAILS
detailsID  orderID  productName
1             1      pillow
2             1      mattress
3             2      pillow
4             3      sheets
5             3      headboard
6             3      mattress
7             4      pillow
8             4      framed art
9             4      decals
10            4      plant stand
```

In my query, I want to select all from orders where the date = today. I am joining the ORDERDETAILS table because I want to know anytime I sold a pillow in my results.

I only want 1 row per order to be displayed in the results so in orderID 1 for example, they ordered a pillow and mattress. In the results under productName for that row, I want it to display pillow.

If someone didn't order a pillow, I still need the row to show for their order today and under productName I dont care what it shows if it's not a pillow. It can show nothing or one of the other product names they ordered.

I know this doesn't work:

```
SELECT ORDERS.*, ORDERDETAILS.*
FROM ORDERS INNER JOIN ORDERDETAILS ON ORDERS.orderID = ORDERDETAILS.orderID
WHERE productName = "pillow"
```

I am not sure if I need subqueries or some sort of outer left join maybe both?

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I just discovered the SQL Case Statement: https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-case/, it looks like that may be the easiest way for me if it gets the right results, trying ti now!

Comment: well, this is a cool feature but not what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
select detailsID, a.orderID, productName, customerName, orderDate from 
(
    select detailsID, orderID, productName from ORDERDETAILS where productName = 'pillow'
    union 
    select detailsID, orderID, productName from
    (
    select detailsID, orderID, productName, rank()over(partition by orderID order by detailsID) as _Rank from ORDERDETAILS  
    )a where _Rank = 1
    and orderID not in (select orderID from ORDERDETAILS where productName = 'pillow')
) a
inner join Orders b on a.orderID = b.orderID
```

Output:

```
detailsID   orderID productName customerName    orderDate
1   1   pillow  John Smith  2/21/2020
3   2   pillow  Bill Adams  2/21/2020
4   3   sheets  Susan Conrad    2/21/2020
7   4   pillow  Amy Fetcher 2/21/2020
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only interested in *some* order details, but *all* headers, you want a `LEFT JOIN`. And since you only want to filter the results from `ORDERDETAILS`, you'll want your filtering criteria in the `JOIN`, rather than in a `WHERE` clause that also applies to the `ORDERS` table.

```
SELECT ORDERS.*, ORDERDETAILS.*
FROM 
  ORDERS 
LEFT JOIN ORDERDETAILS 
  ON ORDERS.orderID = ORDERDETAILS.orderID
  AND productName = "pillow"
```

That should get you most of the way there. If there's a possibility of more than one detail record per order that includes `pillow`, then you'll want to use a sub-query against the details table to skinny it down further to just the information you're interested in. And at that point, I'd move the filter into the sub-query.